# Are buffer overflow exploits still a practical intrusion method?

Tags: security, exploit

With many of the built in (non-added by a user) security measures, are buffer overflow exploits still a practical intrusion method?

What are the major security measures that negate buffer overflow?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Check the bugs fixed in your OS and you'll see buffer overflows patched. See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5130 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Operating systems and compilers do a lot to try to prevent buffer overflows, but they are certainly still at problem.

The easiest way to avoid buffer overflow is to avoid languages like C that force you to manage buffers (and their sizes) in the first place. If, quite possibly, you cannot avoid using C-like languages, there are a bunch of ways to help mitigate potential problems:

Here's a start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection

Answer (score 0):

Buffer overflows are still a common way to break into native applications, although I suspect the number of people practically exploiting them offensively for real-world intrusions is still quite low because of OS protection mechanisms such as ASLR and DEP and compiler protection mechanisms such as GS cookies (stack canaries).

Stack overflows are often not exploitable nowadays because advances in modern compilers mean that most (but not all) stack-overflows are detected during function execution causing the process to crash rather than yield execution to the attacker.

Heap overflows are very much exploitable, even on modern OSes, and must always be treated as critical.

Unfortunately there's no hard and fast rule as to whether any given *specific* stack or heap overflow is practically exploitable, however from a defensive point of view, all compiler and OS mitigations are just that - mitigations. They slow attackers down rather than stopping them, and if you're a security researcher you need to report both stack overflows and heap overflows as critical problems, and as a developer you need to fix them immediately.